# How to build a lookup table in C (SDCC compiler) with linear interpolation

Tags: c, linear-interpolation

For a LPC922 microcontroller (with SDCC) I want to create a lookup table with linear interpolation.
Lets assume I got x and y values like

```
x=300 y=10,0201 
x=700 y=89,542 
x=800 y=126,452 
x=900 y=171,453 
x=1500 y=225,123
```

How can the code for a lookup table with linear interpolation look like, so I get for example for x=850 the right value for y ((171,453+126,452)/2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef struct { double x; double y; } coord_t;

coord_t c[5] = 
{
    {300, 10.02},
    {700, 89.542},
    {800, 126.452}, 
    {900, 171.453}, 
    {1500,225.123}
};    

double interp( coord_t* c, double x, int n )
{
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < n-1; i++ )
    {
        if ( c[i].x <= x && c[i+1].x >= x )
        {
            double diffx = x - c[i].x;
            double diffn = c[i+1].x - c[i].x;

            return c[i].y + ( c[i+1].y - c[i].y ) * diffx / diffn; 
        }
    }

    return 0; // Not in Range
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    double y = interp( c, 850, 5 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double get_value(double x)
{
    /* NOTE: xs MUST be sorted */
    static const double xs[] = { 300, 700, 800, 900, 1500 };
    static const double ys[] = { 10.0201, 89.542, 126.452, 171.453, 225.123 };

    /* number of elements in the array */
    static const int count = sizeof(xs)/sizeof(xs[0]);

    int i;
    double dx, dy;

    if (x < xs[0]) {
        /* x is less than the minimum element
         * handle error here if you want */
        return ys[0]; /* return minimum element */
    }

    if (x > xs[count-1]) {
        return ys[count-1]; /* return maximum */
    }

    /* find i, such that xs[i] <= x < xs[i+1] */
    for (i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        if (xs[i+1] > x) {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* interpolate */
    dx = xs[i+1] - xs[i];
    dy = ys[i+1] - ys[i];
    return ys[i] + (x - xs[i]) * dy / dx;
}
```

This can fairly easily be extended to other [interpolation methods](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) if you wish. Note that you will then probably have to extend the special cases for the border regions however you wish to handle that. A common method is to do linear interpolation when not enough neighboring values are available for the preferred method.

Also when the number of values starts to grow i would recommend using a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) method to compute the starting point. This shouldn't be a problem with this few values though.

Update: Since OP is working on a limited platform, here's a version of the above using [libfixmath](http://code.google.com/p/libfixmath/):

```
/* NOTE: xs MUST be sorted */
static const fix16_t xs[] = { 300<<16, 700<<16, 800<<16, 900<<16, 1500<<16 };
static const fix16_t ys[] = { (fix16_t)(65536.0*10.0201+0.5), (fix16_t)(65536.0*89.542+0.5), (fix16_t)(65536.0*126.452+0.5), (fix16_t)(65536.0*171.453+0.5), (fix16_t)(65536.0*225.123+0.5) };

fix16_t get_value_fix(fix16_t x)
{    
    /* number of elements in the array */
    static const int count = sizeof(xs)/sizeof(xs[0]);
    int i;
    fix16_t dx, dy;

    if (x < xs[0]) {
        /* x is less than the minimum element
         * handle error here if you want */
        return ys[0]; /* return minimum element */
    }

    if (x > xs[count-1]) {
        return ys[count-1]; /* return maximum */
    }

    /* find i, such that xs[i] <= x < xs[i+1] */
    for (i = 0; i < count-1; i++) {
        if (xs[i+1] > x) {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* interpolate */
    dx = fix16_sub(xs[i+1], xs[i]);
    dy = fix16_sub(ys[i+1], ys[i]);
    return fix16_add(ys[i],  fix16_div(fix16_mul(fix16_sub(x, xs[i]), dy), dx));
}
```

Comment: @Stefan: Browsing the manual for SDCC it looks like it only supports floats. In that case all the `double` declarations should be changed to `float` and all the constants should have `.0f` or simply `f` appended. Of course you might also want to use fixed point arithmetic instead.

Comment: For the first try I changed it to int and just just fixed values without point. The problem with your solution is that Eclipse is saying:
?ASlink-Error-Could not get 534 consecutive bytes in internal RAM for area DSEG.
at 1: warning 119: don't know what to do with file '
'. file extension unsupported
make: *** [test.hex] Error 1
make: Target `all' not remade because of errors.

If I use just 4 or less values it is alright, but if I use more it seems that there is not enough RAM for it.

Comment: You can even store the last index in a static variable and start the search from this point, since typically, linear interpolation routines are called in a sequential manner.

Comment: @Stefan: Looks like it might be placing the data in a r/w segment rather than in read-only segment. Try moving `xs` and `ys` outside of the function, though I doubt that will help.

Comment: @user786653 Thank you very much, that seems to work. Now I get my hex File for the µC, but at the moment its still not working correctly. But I will try to find that out. Thanks

Comment: it is running, @user786653 thank you very much for your support. You have been a very big help for me. Thanks

Comment: @Stefan: Great! :) Since you're new here: remember to upvote the posts you found useful and accept the answer if you think it's adequate. see the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: Thanks, at the moment I have not enough vote your answer up. But I clicked yes for the question if your post was useful. It was very useful so thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the values in an array. Then search for x.. if you didn't find the correct value you have an index and a neighbour index, then calculate the value using your formula..

Comment: But how to find the index and neighbour index if I cant find the correct value?